# Could a "not constructive" question be otherwise described as "incomplete?

Tags: discussion, questions

For instance, the question, "How do I play England in Diplomacy?" is not a good question, because it's broad and open-ended.

"When playing Diplomacy as England, how do I choose where to try get a foothold on the Continent, and which enemy to fight?" is a more focused question.

Can it be said, that the second question is a "more complete" version of the first, and that a "not constructive" question can often be improved by making it "more complete?"

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call that question "Not constructive".  I would call it overly broad, which is listed under the definition for "Not a real question".  "Incomplete" questions as you call them seem to be a subset of "Not a real question" then, and obviously they can be improved by making the question less broad or vague.